# Need help on how to use tables from database in project

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework

I created an ASP.NET MVC project in Visual Studio and I managed to connect it to my faculty's database and all the tables are there.

There is just one issue: I cannot manipulate the tables using C# code using Entity Framework (deleting, creating, updating rows).

Any help would be appreciated. I am NOT working with ASP.NET Core MVC.

Comment: When you say that you cannot manipulate the tables, what does that mean? You don't know how? Your code is throwing an error? Your code is not throwing an error but no changes are being made? If it is either of the latter two please can you post the code that you are using?

Comment: I have tried some things but none of them work. So now i have no code for that.

Comment: Create context - code first from database if you want to work with existing database structure https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-from-existing-database.aspx

Comment: The thing is i am using POSTGRESQL for my project, so Code First doesn't work.

Comment: are there any other ideas you can give me ??

Comment: In entity framework core you supposed to have a valid context derived from DbContext in order to manipulate data in the database. In the case of the existing database, you have to create a valid context firstly. You may do it manually, but I suggest automatic scaffolding via scaffold command: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-dbcontext-scaffold. But in some cases, automatic scaffolding gives a result which you may want to change a little bit manually.